# A random crossword

Tags: crosswords

I've made a crossword using this [site](https://crosswordlabs.com/). You can post partial and/or complete answers. Solution will be posted next week.

[image: crossword puzzle custom made]

Comment: Looks like this one **is** tough, ha?

Answer (score 1):

This is far as I got.

Across:

3.Eureka

4.Huh

8.Patching

15.Quanta

Down:

12.Bouillabaisse

Comment: In addition to Bobo's answer above: Across:
21. Exposed

Comment: Found another one but could not comment the same answer got no reps :( > `Down 2: prevaricate`

Comment: 5 Down: praise. That's all I have for now